# blpop from redis is idling

Tags: ruby, redis, queue

I have a process popping from redis queue in blocking fashion.

```
list, data = redis.blpop(key)
```

However, sometimes, the process will become idle. It's idling not because redis queue is consumed. There're still data inside it. The process will get data from redis as soon as I re-start the program. It's very difficult to debug here. Any idea why this is happening here?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-blocking fashion"? The Ruby redis driver *is* blocking if I recall correctly.

Comment: sounds like a bug in the library

Comment: @Agis thanks, I made the correction.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer could be, but not likely since redis is quite reliable.

Comment: @seanan redis is reliable, no idea about the client library

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I'm using the client lib provided by redis.

Comment: @seanan the only library that's actually a part of redis itself is the C library.